# Web ApI Entity Framework (Code First) Value not appearing in database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, api, rest, ef-code-first

My database will run correctly, and I can input the data manually via SQL Server, however, when I try and pass the value in via my API (testing using Postman), the value won't pass into the database, it appears as "NULL".

I have a reports and a bookings tables.

This is the code for the reports:

```
public class Report
{

    public Report()
    {
        Injuries = new List<Injury>();
        this.Bookings = new HashSet<Booking>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Club1 { get; set; }
    public string Club2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Injury> Injuries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    }
```

Bookings:

```
public class Booking
{
    //public Booking()
    //{
    //    Reports = new List<Report>();
    //}

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Club { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public string PlayerNumber { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //public int? Report_Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Report_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Report Report { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
     //POST: api/Reports
     [ResponseType(typeof(Report))]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostReport(Report report)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Reports.Add(report);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = report.Id }, report);
    }
```

I put the test information via Postman:

[image: I put the test information via Postman but the report_Id1 value won't pass into the database]

[image: Value appears as NULL]

[image: The information I enter manually via SQL Server, works fine.]

[image: I edit the Report_Id1 for Steven Gerrard and it appears when I call it via GET]

I'm not sure why Report_Id is showing as it's not required, however, Report_Id1 is the field that is connecting the Report and Booking together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your foreign key doesn't follow convention (ReportId), you need to use the annotation [ForeignKey] or a fluent api configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.Report) 
            .WithMany(b => b.Bookings) 
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Report_Id);
```

That is why EF is adding the second Report_ID1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx